# How to pass values from ngModel to the constructor of an object

Tags: html, typescript

I have an HTML file that takes some user input and submits it as a "contact form". Once the user enters their information I am using NgMoel to get those inputs and pass them to the constructor of my object "contactForm". When debugging the code I'm able to see the values being assigned but when passed to the constructor, the object shows that it's undefined and empty.

here is the HTML file:

```
<section class="hero is-fullheight">
    <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
        <p class="title">
            <a>Contact From</a>
        </p>
        <p class="subtitle">
            <a>Do you have any question or concerns? fill out this form to contact us.</a>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="container has-text-left">

            <div class="tile">
                <div class="tile is-vertical is-12">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div class="tile is-parent">
                            <article class="tile is-child notification is-link">
                                
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label class="label has-text-white">Name</label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input class="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="First and Last Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label class="label has-text-white">Email</label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input class="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label class="label has-text-white">Subject</label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <div class="select">
                                            <select [(ngModel)]="subject" required>
                                                <option>Select dropdown</option>
                                                <option>Order question</option>
                                                <option>Shipping question</option>
                                                <option>Other</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label class="label has-text-white">Message</label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <textarea class="textarea" type="text" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Add you message here" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox">
                                            I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field is-grouped">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <button class="button is-link" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <button class="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

this is the TS file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { FormService } from '../services/form.service';
import { Form } from './form';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit{

  name!: string;
  email!: string;
  subject!: string;
  message!: string;

  contactForm:Form = new Form(this.name, this.email, this.subject, this.message);

  constructor(private _snackbar: MatSnackBar, private formService: FormService, private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.contactForm);
    this.formService.submitForm({form: this.contactForm});
  }
}
```

and here is the From.TS file that the where the constructor is

```
export class Form{
       constructor(
        name:String,
        email:String,
        subject:String,
        message:String
    ){}
}
```

once the object is created it would pass that object to a service that does a post request. I tested the back end request with postman and it works fine. I think my issue is with the TypeScript and creating that Form object.
Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<div` nesting may be broken - indentation is. Is it `From.TS` or Form.TS?

Answer (score 0):

You have Created the instance of Form in start when your component loaded. You should create the instance when you click on submit button and pass that instance to your service.

for reference: [Stack blitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztkjdh?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcontack-form%2Fcontack-form.module.ts,src%2Fcontact-form%2Fcontact-form.component.ts,src%2Fcontact-form%2Fcontact-form.component.html,src%2Fmodel%2Fform.ts)

Comment: Tried this but for some reason the constructor was not assigning the values. What I ended up doing was adding setter and getter methods and that worked.